# How Do I Containerize Eureka Server In Docker

Tags: java, docker, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, service-discovery

i have been struggling to use my created eureka-server container in docker...
I have gone through previous solutions and am still not getting why i cant access the url: http://localhost:8761/
I have changed my properties file severally but no one seems to be working...
Firstly my application.properties file goes like this

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
server.port=8761
spring.application.name=discovery-service
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils=trace
spring.cloud.inetutils.timeout-seconds=10
```

And my dependecies tag of my pom.xml goes like this

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And i have also added the @EnableEurekaServer to my application class...
So when i created an image for it using the docker command docker build -t davidtega/eureka-layered -f Dockerfile.layered .
It worked perfectly, and i started a container using the docker command docker run -p 8761:8761 -t davidtega/eureka-layered
And this the log
[image]

But when i try to access http://localhost:8761/, this site cannot be reached is the response i get everytime...
So i noticed my app was running on 0.0.0.0:8761 not 127.0.0.1:8761
[image]

I was wondering how do i change it ???
I have two docker files, the first one is the DockerFile and the second one is the Dockerfile.layered
For my DockerFile, this is what is in it...

```
FROM openjdk:17

COPY target/*.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

And my DockerFile.layered file contains

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17.0.4.1_1-jre as builder
WORKDIR extracted
ADD target/*.jar app.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar app.jar extract

FROM eclipse-temurin:17.0.4.1_1-jre
WORKDIR application
COPY --from=builder extracted/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder extracted/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=builder extracted/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder extracted/application/ ./
EXPOSE 8761
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

Please and please help i request assistance, i am using spring cloud version 2.7 and java 17... Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your docker is running on 127.0.0.1?

Comment: i dont know ??? how do i check

Comment: @whiplash  or how to solve this issue

Comment: do a docker run with port mapping:

docker run -p 8761

Comment: @paltaa ok i will do that now

Comment: @paltaa that is what am doing with this command, docker run -p 8761:8761 -t davidtega/eureka-layered , and the application is starting successfully but i just cant access the localhost:8761 on the browser

Comment: could you post your Dockerfile and check that the port is bound to that process with  lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN

Comment: @paltaa ok i have updated the post and added my dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the config `eureka.hostname=localhost` and `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/`

Make sure the port is mapped doing a `docker run -p 8761` and then check that the port is correctly listening with `lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`

Comment: i ran the command docker run -d -p 8761 davidtega/eureka-layered, and i was able to access my eureka server on http://localhost:57072/

Comment: ok i will try that as well

Comment: okay you are done then

Comment: Great! You can acept the answer now, will edit it with all the details